# dynamically allocate memeory for Eigen Vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I am using the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) linear algebra library. I struggling trying to allocate Eigen Vectors in the constructor in a class, and then calling the elements of those vectors.

For example,

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::VectorXd;
#include <memory>
using std::unique_ptr;

class Cl
{
public:
    unique_ptr<VectorXd> v;

    Cl(const int n);
    ~Cl(void);
}
Cl::Cl(const int n)
{
    auto v= unique_ptr<VectorXd>(new VectorXd(n));
}
Cl::~Cl(void)
{
    v= nullptr;
}

main(void)
{
    Cl cl(10);

    /* call an element of v how? */

}
```

For example, using "cl.v(2)" gives me the compiler error (I am using clang++)

```
error: type 'unique_ptr<VectorXd>' (aka 'unique_ptr<Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> >') does
      not provide a call operator
```

while using "cl.(*v)(2)" gives me

```
error: expected unqualified-id
        cout << cl.(*v)(2) << endl;
```

I am new to c++, so I may be missing something very basic here.

Comment: Wrong tool for the wrong job. `std::vector` looks more appropriate for this use case than `std::unique_ptr`. You're looking for `std::vector`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to use the Eigen Vector for some later linear algebraic manipulations are you suggesting I use vector<VectorXd>?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik do I need to manually allocate memory of vector<VectorXd>? Otherwise, wouldn't it go out of scope once the constructor finishes?

Comment: The whole purpose of `std::vector` is to manage dynamically-allocated memory, and destroy it when the vector gets destroyed. No, the vector does not get destroyed when the constructor finishes. That's now how C++ objects work. For more information, see your C++ book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you trying to dynamically allocate the `Eigen::VectorXd v;` itself? Unless you would like to extend the lifetime of `v` beyond the lifetime of `cl` (in which case you would indeed have to do so), I would recommend to follow the following simple example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::VectorXd;

class Cl
{
public:
   VectorXd v;
    Cl(int n) : v(n) {}
    ~Cl() {}
}

int main()
{
    Cl cl(10);
    for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        cl.v(i) = i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe in addition to the answers already regarding std::vector you are also misusing your 'unique_ptr', if indeed you actually require the use of one (reference ggael answer). Please see below example on the use of unique_ptr:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Cl {
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>> v;
        Cl(const int size, int default_values);
        ~Cl(void);
        int Size();
};

Cl::Cl(const int size, int default_values = 0) {
    v.reset(new std::vector<int>(size, default_values));
}

Cl::~Cl(void) {
    // do not require to reset/destroy an auto_ptr so this can be ommitted 
}

int Cl::Size() {
    return v->size();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Cl blob(10);
    int size = blob.Size();
    std::cout << size << std::endl;
}
```

In your provided code you're declaring a new auto in the constructor rather than using the variable you've defined in your Public class definition. I've included a 'Size' method so you can see the scope extends beyond the constructor.